# Handle signals in the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, jvm, process, posix, signals

Is it possible to handle POSIX signals within the Java Virtual Machine?

At least [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_(POSIX)) and [SIGKILL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL) should be quite platform independent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The JVM responds to signals on its own. Some will cause the JVM to shutdown gracefully, which includes running shutdown hooks. Other signals will cause the JVM to abort without running shutdown hooks.

Shutdown hooks are added using [Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

I don't think the JDK provides an official way to handle signals within your Java application. However, I did find [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/i-signalhandling/), which describes using some undocumented `sun.misc.Signal` class to do exactly that. The article dates from 2002 and uses JDK 1.3.1, but I've confirmed that the `sun.misc.Signal` class still exists in JDK 1.6.0.

Comment: This article could be useful for any JVM, but it refers only for IBM JVMs (Note: The signal handling described in this article is available with the IBM JVM, versions 1.3.1 and 1.4.2 only.)

Comment: I think [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.win.80.doc/user/signals.html) is the new location of the IBM article.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [Runtime#addShutdownHook](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) ?