# Unable to kill Flask server launched by Popen on Ubuntu

Tags: python, flask, popen

Here is the reduced requirement of what I am trying to achieve.

```
# run.py
import requests
import time

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

server = Popen("./app.py", stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
time.sleep(1)
res = requests.get("http://localhost:1234/")
assert res.status_code == 200
server.kill()
server.terminate()
res = requests.get("http://localhost:1234/")
print res
```

And the actual server script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, make_response, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def view():
    return make_response("")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", port=1234)
```

On the command line I run `python run.py`. From shell:

```
(t)yeukhon@fubini:/tmp$ ps aux|grep app
yeukhon  21452  0.6  0.4  16416  9992 pts/2    S    03:50   0:00 python ./app.py
yeukhon  21471  0.0  0.0   4384   804 pts/2    S+   03:51   0:00 grep --color=auto app
```

So `app.py` is still hanging there. I have to kill it from the command line. In fact, the last line of `run.py` tells us the server was still alive (200 was returned).

I tried to kill with `os.kill(server.pid, signal.SIGTERM)` and `os.kill(server.pid, signal.SIGKILL)` but none works.

Normally `kill` will work, but I am really not sure why it can't receive the signal. I am sure somehow Flask is refusing to stop.

What options do I have?

strangely, my script above works perfectly fine on Mac OSX (I am on 10.8.5, Mountain Lion). So far I have tested on two Ubuntu 12.04 machines and they have the same behavior. I am running Python 2.7.3 on both Ubuntu machines and Python 2.7.2 on my Mac OSX.

**correction**:
The only option I have is to use http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/67/. But I prefer not to. And yes, I have to launch one using Popen.

Comment: Hi CppLearner. I encountered the same issue. However, it seems like I have to set shell=True for running the flask through popen. Otherwise, I will get error message like "raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory". Therefore, I wonder how you revised your code finally. When shell=True, the server started from popen just keep running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying `shell=True`, the command is run by subshell.

```
server = Popen("./app.py", stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
```

`server.terminate` will kill the subshell, but web server will not be killed.

---

How to verify this? Try `print server.pid` after the `Popen` call, and compare that with `ps` output.

Comment: Yes. That works. I misunderstood the usage of ``shell``. But what do you mean with the verification line? Also, why can't a daemonized process be killed? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CppLearner, output of `print server.pid` and `ps ..| grep ..` will be different.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any good resource to help me understand this better? I don't mean to go through my OS book again. Sorry but appreciate your help.

Comment: @CppLearner, Sorry, non-daemonized process also does not be affected. (at least in Linux). removed that clause from the answer.

Comment: @CppLearner, See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269494/how-can-i-cause-a-child-process-to-exit-when-the-parent-does  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395877/are-child-processes-created-with-fork-automatically-killed-when-the-parent-is

Answer (score 2):

Remove `shell=True` from your Popen. This will make the first request. Kill the process. And then throw an exception for the second attempt.

Comment: While we are at it, do you know of any good place to understand this area better (I don't mean to go through my thick OS course book again). Sorry but thanks.

Comment: @CppLearner understand what?

Comment: :) nvm. falsetru provided some. Was interested in improving my usage of popen.

Answer (score 0):

Problem quite old but I met similar when I was running flask server with `subprocess.Popen` in `conftest.py` with `pytest` in docker container on Mac OS.
This piece of code is not working for me (in `conftest.py`)

```py
flask_server_proc = subprocess.Popen([
  'python', 'code/flask_server/main.py',
  '--local'
])

flask_server_proc.kill()
```

Parent process was killed but server still was running and answering requests.
So I did this:

```py
import psutil
import subprocess

server = subprocess.Popen([
    'python', 'code/flask_server/main.py',
    '--mysql-user', 'root',
    '--mysql-password', 'pass',
    '--mysql-host', 'mysql',
    '--local-artifact-store'
])

# Here I check if server is up. For example with some health check
# url. Sleep mimics it.
import time
time.sleep(10)
print(server.pid)

# Somewhere here you will call 'yield server'. This is just snippet
# with potential solution of problem so no yielding it.
# The next part should be run after 'yield server'.

# This should kill server.
# server.kill()

# Actually it should be one such process like flask.
flask_to_kill: List[psutil.Process] = []
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if 'code/flask_server/main.py' in process.cmdline():
        flask_to_kill.append(process)

def on_terminate(proc: psutil.Process):
    print("process {} terminated with exit code {}".format(proc, proc.returncode))

for f in flask_to_kill:
    f.terminate()

gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs(flask_to_kill, timeout=3, callback=on_terminate)

for to_stab in alive:
    to_stab.kill()
```

so looks like remedy is to use `psutil` package to kill server after tests.
Happy hacking!