# When will the child process die when parent process is killed?

Tags: linux

In a program A, it calls a script B. And in the script B, it calls wpa_supplicant directly (not via this way: systemctl start wpa_supplicant) to config WIFI network. And we found that if the program A is killed, sometimes the network will be disconnected while sometimes the network keeps connected.

```
program A -> call script B -> call wpa_supplicant
```

So I want to know why?
In my understanding, if the parent process is killed, then the child process will die automatically, right? Why sometimes the network keeps connected? Which means the child process wpa_supplicant is still alive, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are child processes created with fork() automatically killed when the parent is killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/395877/608639) Also see [How to make child process die after parent exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/284325/608639)

Comment: In my case, wpa is killed sometimes, while sometimes it keeps alive. How to explain this? According to your reply, I can not find the answer when will the child process be killed.

Answer (score 1):

When the parent process terminates before the child process, the child process remains as a so called [*orphan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) process on the system until it terminates. After it terminates, it will become a [*zombie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) until it gets reaped by `init`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! In my case, wpa is killed sometimes, while sometimes it keeps alive. How to explain this? According to your reply, I can not find the answer when will the child process be killed.

Comment: It won't get killed. I guess it just terminates itself. Check syslog for the reason.

Comment: That system uses systemd. But due to wpa is invoked by script, so no journal log. And the test result shows that in 10 test cases, 3 of them will occur WIFI networks disconnected issue, and the rest 7 of them will keep network connected.

Comment: systemd is unrelated to (r)syslog. Just check `/var/log/syslog` (or `/var/log/messages`, depending on your system)