# what is this code result? and why is like that?

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, sleep, child-process

What is the reason for the code result?
And what happens when an exception happens in the `fork()`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
int main(){
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){
        int child=getpid();
        printf("child: parent %d\n",getppid());
        sleep(4);
        printf("child: parent %d\n",getppid());
        sleep(100);
    }
    else{
        int parent=getpid();
        printf("parent: parent %d\n",getppid());
        sleep(2);
        int zero=0;
        int i=3/zero;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
parent: parent 63742
child: parent 63825
Floating point exception (core dumped)
ubunto@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ child: parent 4497
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indent the code. While it doesn't matter for the compiler, it does for us humans trying to read and understand the code.

Comment: When the parent dies, its chidren are "adopted" (the kernel forcibly sets their PPID) by `init` (PID 1)

Comment: @pmg can you explain why the parent dies?

Comment: dividing by zero is a "death sentence"

Comment: @pmg and what happens if we don't use sleep function? I mean why do we use sleep()?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I added the output

Comment: `sleep()`, in the posted code, forces the events in different processes to happen in the sequence expected by the programmer ... without it the order of events in different processes would be "random".

Comment: The program is designed to demonstrate the "adoption" mechanism described by pmg. In order to do that, the parent needs to crash between the two `printf()` calls in the child. The easiest way to achieve that is to have a long sleep in the child, and a shorter sleep in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the time sequence of the execution:

**Second 0:**

1. `fork()` issued
2. The parent process prints its pid (63742)
3. The child process prints its pid (63825)
4. Both processes issue a sleep

**Second 1:**

- Both processes are sleeping

**Second 2:**

1. Parent process wakes up. Child process will sleep for 2 further seconds
2. Parent process issues a division by 0 causing an exception and the program abnormal termination

In order to examine in depth what happens in case the parent process terminates before its child I suggest checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/395877/11336762) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/284325/11336762).

Comment: Hmmm ... **second 2: the parent wakes up and attempts to divide by zero**

Comment: @pmg you are right... I corrected it. In my defence it was correct in my brain but my fingers typed the opposite..

Comment: Fingers are awesome! ;-)