# Creating a clear button

Tags: java, awt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I restart a Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159802/how-can-i-restart-a-java-application)

i am working on a java program which takes in bunch of values from the user and returns an answer. i have a "clear" button which makes the application ready to for a new set of input. So what i want is that this button should close the frame currently being viewed(create a window closing event and so on) and then call the main() function to create a new instance of my application. How should i do it? I tried this but it closes everything and the new frame doesn't show up:

```
WindowEvent wev = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(wev);
main(newInstance);
```

and also what does Toolkit do? suggest some readings for that. Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need a new instance of the application? Should you not have your application handle this by clearing any text fields and restarting?
I think if you keep calling your main again each time you're going to end up with memory leak issues as you build a stack of mains running.
Are you using swing?
What is wrong with just setting the text of any text fields back to their default?

Comment: yes but the application is actually big, it has three classes and a LOT of variables and i tried that. It was confusing and exhausting. just clearing the textfields and setting variables to default is not helping. besides i am also drawing in one of my panel, and then i have to call repaint and then yes lots of work. This is neat and easy :P

Comment: Did you use any kind of coding structure such as MVC? I think perhaps it may be useful in future to use a real structure so that you can easily do these things. 

I'll post an answer which may work for you, but I with a valid structure you would be able to just create new models, views or controllers as you wish, rather than needing to restart your application.

Answer (score 0):

as per my comments I don't think this is best practise, but it is possible.

This has already been answered here:
[How can I restart a Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159802/how-can-i-restart-a-java-application)

I hope this helps,

Comment: This is not an answer, please flag the post as duplicate and link the question instead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that before, I appreciate that. I've flagged it as a duplicate. Hopefully this helps the poster.

Comment: you guys didnt get me, i am not rying to "restart" i was just trying to do this, so simple:myFrameInstance.setVisible(false);
  main(newInstance);