# How to restart an application in Java?

Tags: java, actionlistener, restart

Ones my application finishes executing, I need to restart it in order to be able to reuse it again. My application has multiple threads (and some chromedriver.exe issues). Therefore, I prefer NOT to create additional threads in order to restart it. Currently I am simply closing the GUI window and then reopen my application by double clicking on the **application.exe** file.

I am curious if there is a way I could add an **actionListener** to a **"RESTART"** button that would close and reopen my application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159802/how-can-i-restart-a-java-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("my App");
 System.exit(0);
```