# Specify a default classloader in a jar's manifest

Tags: java, classloader

Is there a way to specify a default classloader in a jar's manifest? I'd like `java -jar Foo.jar` to use a custom one, not the default, without having to do `-Djava.system.class.loader=...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any other way than using the system property. I would write a small launcher app or script for this like already mentioned in another answer.

If you are okay with a hack though, you could check if your own classloader is used when the application starts and if it isn't, you can [restart the java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159802/how-can-i-restart-a-java-application) and add the `-Djava.system.class.loader` option to the command.

Comment: Yeah; I didn't think it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a solution by adding a custom field in your manifest file and creating an executable script (ie .bat, etc) that would read your jre version field and start the jar appropriately