# Run Java from Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux

I am writing a program that updates it's self. I get all the updating working, I just need the program to restart it's self. Here is my current code:

```
String javaPath = System.getProperty("java.home");
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(javaPath, "-jar", ClientPortal.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).start();
```

I get an error though:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre": error=13, Permission denied
```

I tried running this in my own console, and it is denied. The reason I am using the path of Java instead of just using the command `java`, is because, like me, people might have multiple Java instances installed and the wrong one is run. The command might simply be not available.

How can I run the same JVM in this fashion?

Comment: Isn't that a directory? You can't execute a directory; try `javaPath + "/java"`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Actually it's `javaPath + "/bin/java"`. This doesn't solve the problem of `.exe` on Windows though.

Comment: Discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159802/how-can-i-restart-a-java-application