# How to automatically restart jar file on crash

Tags: executable, executable-jar

I have an executable jar file in a folder with other files and sometimes the jar file crashes, is there something that would automatically restart the file when it crashes because i need this jar file to be running at all times

Answer (score 4):

For example in bash you can wrap a process into next script `respawner.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

until "$@"; do
    echo "Process crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
    sleep 5
done
```

and then use it as `./respawner.sh java -jar yourJarfile.jar`
If the Jvm crashes the script will wait for 5 seconds and restarts it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing you should do is investigate why the JVM crashes (It's the Java Virtual Machine, your `java` program, and not the JAR file that crashes), how it crashes (e.g. are you running out of memory -- sometimes tuning the JVM correctly may reduce or even eliminate crashes etc.). Having done that to an extent you can, you should look at using a watchdog. A watchdog is a program that watches another program and restarts it upon failure. See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159802/how-can-i-restart-a-java-application) discussion.