# How to run JAR program from same JAR?

Tags: java, jar, startup

I have some app and sometimes is lagging.
It's mean I need restart program - run same JAR file from desktop.

How can I do this?

My idea is:

```
runNewInstanceOfProgram(); //how can I start new process if same jar file?
closeActualProgram(); //some System.exit(0);
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If it is lagging after some amount of run time, you have a memory leak..

Comment: what do you actually want to do? restart some external JAR?

Comment: Here is what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159802/how-can-i-restart-a-java-application