# Java: How do i restart the program?

Tags: java, swing, animation, actionlistener

So i made this game type program that restarts the game once you click on reset button but idk how to make it functional.. This is what i did but the only thing it does is creates a new java program of the game. It doesn't get rid of the old one or anything.. here is my code for restarting.. What codes should i add :/

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new Tests();
    }
});
```

Comment: "but idk how to make it functional." it depends what you mean why functional, this term can mean a lot in terms of programming.

Comment: have you searched "reopen java program" in google?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I mean like i know how to put the button but idk how i can restart the game by clicking on it

Comment: @ItamarGreen i googled restart java program but found nothing :/

Comment: @FredJohn refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159802/how-can-i-restart-a-java-application

Comment: @FredJohn: There's no one-size-fits-all solution. You need to give your GUI a reset method of some sort and have this listener call it, and how it works, how it is wired is all dependent on the structure of your program. Myself, I'd strive to make my program in a model-view structure or one of its variants where the program logic (the model) is separate from the GUI code (the view), and then my reset method would tell the model to reset itself (again all depending on how I structure this model) and then this would cause changes to the view. TL;DR: short answer -- your question is unanswerable

Comment: Except that what you **don't** want to do is to create a new JFrame or other window.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i heard u can use frame.dispose(); method but the thing is, my program isn't able to detect the already declared frame outside the actionListener method so when i type in frame.dispose(); i get an error

Comment: No, again you're looking for ready made Swing solutions and that is not what you should be doing. Again, you will want to reset your program to its initial conditions in that method, not disposing of JFrames. Look to your own code, not the Swing library for your solution.