# Java: Reset button isn't working

Tags: java, actionlistener, reset, system.exit

Ok so i am creating this program that when you click on the reset button, it closes the program and opens a new same program from starting however, I am not able to understand how to do it :/ Here is my code for button .. This code basically exits the first program but it doesn't open it again in a new application.

```
 button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                        System.exit(0);
                        new Tests();
                    }

                });
```

Comment: `System.exit(0)` kills everything. The line afterwards is unreachable. If you swap the lines, it won't work either – you have to use something other than `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: `System.exit(0);` forces the closing of the entire VM; whatever you allocate immediately afterwards will simply be discarded.

Comment: You should do something more "discrete".

Comment: you can use this.setVisible(false) instead of System.exit(0)

Comment: Everything they say is true.  So you have to create a whole new process that will exist beyond the lifetime of this process. In otherwords, `System.lang.Runtime.exec("java -jar com.awesome.program.jar")`

Comment: @Socowi hmm i dont know how to reset then.. Please do help :/ idk what to do

Comment: @Omore i wont it to be gone.. not just invisible.

Comment: Copy paste that, obviously replacing your jar file name.  Or better yet do what davidxxx says and use a ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 4):

> This code basically exits the first program but it doesn't open it
>   again in a new application.

`System.exit(0);` terminates the current JVM process.
All instructions after will not be executed.

If you want to restart your application, you should execute the command that starts the JVM of your application. If it is a jar : `java -jar yourJar -cp yourClasspath`.
You can achieve it with a `ProcessBuilder` instance.

The other way is not restarting the application but setting the state of your application at its initial state.

Comment: hmm Idk how to do this reset thing then :/ what do i do please help

Comment: hmm can u provide me an example of that plz :)

Comment: For the first one, look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159802/how-can-i-restart-a-java-application. For the second one, it depends on  your application. Edit and give more detail please if you want a concrete example with it.

Comment: btw sorry for a very noob question but what exactly is jar and how eactly do u check the name

Comment: no problem :) A jar is a basic way to package classes. You can even package in a runnable java application. If you don't use jar you can forget the `-jar` arg...for now :)

Answer (score 2):

`System.exit(0);` kills your entire program. Don't use it until you're really done.

You will want to put your entire program (at least the part you want to execute again) in a loop. When you click your reset button you will kick back to the top (or wherever you want) of the loop. Just remember to have an exit condition to kill the loop, otherwise it will go on forever.

Comment: u mean like while(true) // run codes if(false) move back to the starting?

Comment: while(true) is one way to do you. A better method is to actually have your condition in the while loop. I'm not sure when you're saying with the if(false), as that would never execute.