# Node.JS Parent Process ID

Tags: node.js, process

Is it possible to get the parent process-id using Node.JS? I would like to detect if the parent is killed or fails in such a way that it cannot notify the child. If this happens, the parent process id of the child should become 1.

This would be preferable to requiring the parent to periodically send a keep-alive signal and also preferable to running the `ps` command.

Comment: Do you use system "Child Processes?"

Comment: @Emmerman: I'm not sure what you mean. The parent runs `require('child_process').spawn(process.argv[0], ['path_to_child.js'])` in order to start the child. Then if it needs to talk to the child, it uses the stdin and stdout of the child. stderr is piped to a log. I am guessing the answer would be yes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pid-file. Something like that

```
var util = require('util'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    pidfile = '/var/run/nodemaster.pid';

try {
    var pid = fs.readFileSync(pidfile);
    //REPLACE with your signal or use another method to check process existence :)
    process.kill(pid, 'SIGUSR2'); 
    util.puts('Master already running');
    process.exit(1);
} catch (e) {
    fs.writeFileSync(pidfile, process.pid.toString(), 'ascii');
}

//run your childs here
```

Also you can send pid as argument in `spawn()` call

Comment: I presently use this approach and ran into an issue. If another process reuses your pid it looks like your program is running, when it is in fact an unrelated progarm. There aren't THAT many pids available, so this issue will happen given enough time (took me a few months to run into it).

Answer (score 2):

I start Node.JS from within a native OSX application as a background worker. To make node.js exit when the parent process which consumes node.js stdout dies/exits, I do the following:

```
// Watch parent exit when it dies

process.stdout.resume();
process.stdout.on('end', function() {
  process.exit();
});
```

Easy like that, but I'm not exactly sure if it's what you've been asking for ;-)