# Reliably determine what shell (cmd, bash, or etc) was used to run node.js script

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

As the title states, I'd like determine what shell (`cmd`, `bash`, or etc)  was used to run the node.js script (from within the script).

While detecting the OS with the `os` module can give some clues, it is not enough is some instances, such as as if I were executing from `bash` on `win32` through a terminal like [GitBash](https://git-scm.com/) or [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Is there a property somewhere on the `process` object that has this information?

*Edit: While `process.env.SHELL` is an option, it is not always populated and maybe `undefined` when using some terminals

Comment: Can you get the parent process id (PPID) in node.js? Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541288/detect-when-parent-process-exits

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve by getting this information?  What are you going to do with this information if/when you know it?

Comment: So specifically what i'm trying to do is add support for single quoted string args from a `cmd` shell, starting with detection.  @lit, how could one use a PPID to discover the shell?

Comment: I have recently seen a command that will show what program started a process, but cannot recall it. You can see it in Process Explorer. If I can find it, I will get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `process.env.SHELL` property to get that as seen in the official documentation,

The [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) property returns an object containing the user environment. An example of this object looks like:

```
{
  TERM: 'xterm-256color',
  SHELL: '/usr/local/bin/bash',
  USER: 'maciej',
  PATH: '~/.bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin',
  PWD: '/Users/maciej',
  EDITOR: 'vim',
  SHLVL: '1',
  HOME: '/Users/maciej',
  LOGNAME: 'maciej',
  _: '/usr/local/bin/node'
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `process.env.SHELL` is not guaranteed to be populated.  With some terminals, like Window Command Prompt, it is `undefined`