# Kill a sys.process when the scala process dies?

Tags: scala, process

I have a long-running external process that is started inside a scala program, and I want to have the process die when the scala process dies (or is killed). What's the simplest way to achieve this?

For reference, here's some code (note that `avahi-publish` will still be executing as seen by running `ps aux | grep [a]vahi` even after `Main` terminates):

```
object Main extends App {
  Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor.submit(
    new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        while (true) {
          println("starting avahi publish")
          Try {
            val cmd = "avahi-publish-service 'aname' '_foobar._tcp' 1234"
            Seq("sh", "-c", cmd).!
          } match {
            case Success(r) => println(s"avahi publish terminated: $r")
            case Failure(e) => println(s"avahi publish error: $e")
          }
        }
      }
    })
  // etc etc
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269494/how-can-i-cause-a-child-process-to-exit-when-the-parent-does for a similar question in java. The same answers should be applicable here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there's a guaranteed way to do what you are asking, but you can get close. In Scala (and Java), you can tell the VM to run a block of code for you before it exits in what's called a shutdown hook. By defining a hook, you can have it attempt to kill off your Process before the VM exits.

Note, that in the Scaladoc for [sys.addShutdownHook](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.sys.package), there is a warning: `Note that shutdown hooks are NOT guaranteed to be run.`.

If you alter the way you construct your Process, you can get a reference to the task being run in the background and use it in the hook, as follows (I'm just using a simple `sleep` command):

```
import scala.sys.process.Process

object AppShutdown extends App {
  println("Starting application")
  val proc = Process(Seq("sleep", "50000"))
  val bgProc = proc.run
  sys addShutdownHook {
     println("Caught shutdown, killing process")
     bgProc.destroy
     println(s"Process finished in shutdown hook with code $ev")
  }
  val ev = bgProc.exitValue
  println(s"Process finished naturally with code $ev")

}
```

I hope that helps!