# How to prevent SIGINT signal kills sub processes in Java

Tags: java, exec

I'm using Java exec to run bash script, but when I enter CTRL+C, the Java process will exit and also the sub processes, how can I keep child processes running after JVM is shut down?

```
String command = "ffmpeg -re -strict -2 -i video.mp4 -c:v copy -an -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234";
Utils.writeToFile("sub.sh", command);

new ProcessBuilder("parent.sh", "sub.sh").inheritIO()
        .start().waitFor();
```

parent.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT SIGHUP SIGTSTP
nohup "$@" &
```

I have read answers to similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012662/how-to-prevent-ctrlc-killing-spawned-processes-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394419/creating-a-nohup-process-in-java), e.g, start a  parent bash script in that script run command using nohup, or using trap command to prevent signals,
on my research, it works for example "tail -f somefile", but not for my use case
"ffmpeg -params", please help, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use `setsid` instead of `nohup` in your `parent.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
setsid $@ &
```

---

The first problem is while your Java programm receives a `SIGTERM` signal (after `CTRL + C`), the JVM sends a `SIGKILL` signal to the child processes, which cannot be caught, blocked or ignored. So, once your `parent.sh` process receives `SIGKILL`, it's then passed to its child process `sub.sh` which stops the process.

The second problem is with `nohup "$@" &` you let your `sub.sh` child program run in background, but it is not completely detached from the current terminal. What `nohup` does is basically to ignore the `SIGHUP` signal. It executes the process normally (in the background) and doesn't actually provide daemonization.

Instead of `nohup`, you can use [setsid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid), which detaches the child process `sub.sh` by creating a new session, which will then have no controlling terminal, and thus will no receive the `SIGKILL` signal.

**One other way** to do this might be using `disown`, like `source $@ & disown`, but in this case, it won't block the current terminal in which `parent.sh` is running. The problem is, you won't be able to know, when the child process is completed. So you would have more work to do, in order to monitor the child process id.

Further notes:

- [SIGTERM vs. SIGKILL](https://major.io/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/)
- [Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and)